# If I need to return value from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm totally new in jsp/servlet and working with an application that I have many jsp pages and servlet.
In the first jsp page I choose a customer.

```
<select id ="sel" name="customer">
   <option>customer1</option>
   <option>customer2</option>
   <option>customer3</option>
   <option>customer4</option>
</select>
```

In the second jsp page it shows me  the menu related to this customer(for example I choose configuration and goes to the third jsp page )

```
<% HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
   String chos_cust=request.getParameter("customer");
   session.setAttribute("cust_menu",chos_cust); %>

   ....
<%= session.getAttribute("cust_menu")%>
```

In the third jsp page I choose cateories related to this customer(there are many categories for each customer)
An sql query runs here to show categories as radio buttons:

```
  <input type="radio" name="chos_gr" value="${groups.group_name}"checked > ${groups.group_name}
```

In the forth jsp page according to the chosen category it will show subcategories. In this jsp page I have three div
in html form with hidden type.In the first div list of products has been shown , the second div is for adding a product and in the last div products can be deleted.

```
  String config_gr = request.getParameter("chos_gr");
  session.setAttribute("config_menu",config_gr);
```

I have used a servlet to do these operations(add, delete). It works well but when I add or delete a product and use requestDispstcher/forward in servlet to back to the last jsp to see the result(list of products) it
shows null for category and nothing in list of products.

If I should return the value of category in the servlet to the last jsp?
Could someone tell me what the problem is?

**I can't add a comment for this post. As @underdog suggested I used ${sessionScope.config_menu} in the last jsp and it still shows null for category. It's weird because I get the customer value when I return to the last jsp to see the result but nothing for category.**

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all the object/values in a session attribute. With request dispatcher you forward the flow to a jsp with request & response objects. The request object contains no info of the customer you have set in the session object.

In the jsp try accessing the values from the session scope. 
`${sessionScope.config_menu}` would give you the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a [`response.sendRedirect(url)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)), consider using following:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Above code with the [`getRequestDispatcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) will allow you to include your calling servlet's request by using [`dispatcher.forward`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)), which will include the session attributes you were missing.

[NOTE: OP was already doing the above]

[UPDATE]

Based on the way you were suggesting to code certain parameters in `<input type="hidden" name="myfield">` fields, I suspect, you did nothing else to store the values. Which means, the first time around, they might have been set using the parameters from the previous request, but when using the `dispatcher.forward`, this did not happen.

For fields to be initiated with the appropriate value, they require to be made available either through request parameters (e.g. `GET` parameters, encoded in the URL), or otherwise set within the JSP itself trough `<input type="hidden" value="${whatever}" name="myfield">` or similar code. I am also missing that part of the code to be able to validate.

Using a dispatcher.forward(), you might not have required parameters set.

Comment: I offer my apologies. It looks like the OP was already doing this correctly. However, I will leave this answer out here, as it could potentially help someone else googling and stumbling on a similar issue.